# Append query in access not executing if special characters like ; [ ] etc present in the database filepath

Tags: c#, ms-access, ado.net, append

I am trying to execute the following code in C#.

```
string selQuery = "INSERT INTO [C:\MyDbs\destination.accdb].[Table1] ([No],[Name]) SELECT [No],[Name] FROM [MS Access;DATABASE=C:\MyDbs\abc;def.mdb;pwd=honeywellvft].[Table1]";

dbcommand.CommandText = selQuery;
dbcommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
dbcommand.Connection = myConnObj;
dbcommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Note that the name of the database file here is "abc;def.mdb"

It is failing giving the below Exception.

`{"Could not find file 'C:\\Users\\E330722\\Desktop\\abc'."}`

It is considering the database filepath only till ";" and not considering whole string. How do I solve this problem? I cannot rename filename and/or modify path as they are dynamic inputs, that should not be changed.

This query is executing fine if I rename the file from "abc;def.mdb" to "abcdef.mdb". i.e., removing the special character ";" from file name.

I have tried several options like putting double-quotes "" around db file path, putting single-quotes '', and putting the complete connection string of FROM in double as well as single quotes. But :-(

Comment: Could you copy the problematic file to another one with a more acceptable name?

Answer (score 0):

There is a default path from which your program executes, therefore you should be able to change the default path to the desired subdirectory *before* executing the dbcommand.ExecuteNonQuery(); command.

You would have to parse the string to break it up into path and file name, which shouldn't be too bad. Then use the file name in the connection string and use the path to set your default path prior to the call to DoCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()